# How to search by ID User and not by MongoDB Id?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm consuming an API REST with NodeJs with `POST`, `GET`, `DELETE` and `PUT` verbs.

This is my `mongoose Schema`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    "id": {
        type: Number,
        require: true
    },
    "email": {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    "first_name":{
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    "last_name":{
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    "company":{
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    "url":{
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    "text":{
        type: String,
        require: true
    }     
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

What I'm trying to do is that when I do a `GET`, I want to search by user ID and not by the ID that `MongoDB` gives the user.

The endpoint I want to use:

```
localhost:9000/api/user/[id]
```

The endpoint I don't want to use:

```
localhost:9000/api/user/[MongoDb id]
```

Also I'm trying that when I `GET` the user, I only receive the parameters that I have in the Mongoose Schema and not the ID that MongoDB gives me

Expecting:

If I search a user, I expect this resources:

```
{
    id: 1,
    email: "John@gmail.com",
    first_name: "Smith",
    last_name: "Smith",
    company: "google",
    url: "Smith.com",
    text: "John Smith"
}
```

But not  this

```
{
    _id: 1nf19tg427gnvn9v
    id: 1,
    email: "John@gmail.com",
    first_name: "Smith",
    last_name: "Smith",
    company: "google",
    url: "Smith.com",
    text: "John Smith"
    _v: 1
}
```

This is how I GET the user:

```
 function GetUser(req, res){
    const { id } = req.params;
    userSchema
        .findById(id)
        .then((data) => res.json(data))
        .catch((error) => res.json({ msg: error }))
};
```

**EDIT 1:**

As @Tromgy said, to find by `user ID`, I changed the `GET` to this:

```
 function GetUser(req, res){
    const { id } = req.params;
    userSchema
        .find({id})
        .then((data) => res.json(data))
        .catch((error) => res.json({ msg: error }))
};
```

Now, to finde only the objects I need, I tried only searching `first_name` and `id` with `.then((data) => res.json(data.id, data.first_name))` but Postman stays loading and never show anything...

[image]

Comment: Don't use `findById`, because it expects the `_id`, use `find` instead.

Comment: If I use `find`, y get this `{
    "msg": {}
}`

Comment: I didn´t say anything, I was missing the `({id})`, not `(id)`